# keras predict_generator throwing error after successful training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, yolo

I'm trying to implement [this keras implementation of yolov3](https://github.com/qqwweee/keras-yolo3) on my own dataset from scratch. After changing the code to my requirements and a trial training, I'm trying to verify the predictions through the predict_generator function in keras. However it throws an error.

```
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-4), loss={'yolo_loss': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred},metrics=['accuracy']) # recompile to apply the change
    print('Unfreeze all of the layers.')

    batch_size = 2 
    print('Train on {} samples, val on {} samples, with batch size {}.'.format(num_train, num_val, batch_size))
    model.fit_generator(data_generator_wrapper(lines[:num_train], batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes),
        steps_per_epoch=max(1, num_train//batch_size),
        validation_data=data_generator_wrapper(lines[num_train:], batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes),
        validation_steps=max(1, num_val//batch_size),
        epochs=1,
        initial_epoch=0,
        callbacks=[logging, checkpoint, reduce_lr, early_stopping])
    predict = model.predict_generator(data_generator_wrapper(lines[:num_train], batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes),verbose=1,steps=10)
    model.save_weights(log_dir + 'trained_weights_final.h5')
```

Here is the error

> File "yolo_train.py", line 83, in _main
>       model.predict_generator(data_generator_wrapper(lines[:num_train], batch_size, input_shape, anchors, num_classes),verbose=1,steps=10)
>       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1522, in predict_generator
>       verbose=verbose)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 474, in predict_generator
>       return np.concatenate(all_outs[0])
>   ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

If there were some shape mismatch, I can't understand how the training went fine.Also, I haven't modified any output tensor. Only changed input image size and made the number of classes 1.